# Install "elasticsearch" instead of "pyelasticsearch"

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch, django-haystack

How can I install official elasticsearch binding for python instead of pyelasticsearch?
Haystack documentation says:

> You’ll also need an Elasticsearch binding: elasticsearch-py (NOT
>   pyes). Place elasticsearch somewhere on your PYTHONPATH (usually
>   python setup.py install or pip install elasticsearch).

But when I install elasticsearch with pip, haystack still asks for pyelasticsearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used haystack in my last project. I checked my virtualenv and I have only 'pyelasticsearch==0.5'.
Keep in my mind that documentation can be outdated.

Answer (score 2):

Running

```
pip install elasticsearch
```

did the trick for me.

Comment: I was in the same situation as reported in the question and this did the trick for me.